# How I can get uGUI event parameter?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I'm using new event system, represented in unity 4.6.
Here is example on attaching listener to Toggle component.
My question is: "How can I get Boolean parameter from `On Value Changed(Boolean)`?"

[image: Gui representation]

Currently I'm forced to keeping link of that Toggle object in code and checked new value from it.

```
public void OnVRtoggled() {
    var value = toggleVR.isOn;
}
```

But I think that there must be way of getting boolean value from event. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unity 5.1.2 you just need to add a bool parameter in your callback method

```
public void OnToggledVR(bool isOn) 
{

}
```

[image: Select On Value Changed Callback Step 1]
[image: Select On Value Changed Callback Step 2]

Comment: Not working, unity will using fixed boolean flag which is set in editor: https://i.gyazo.com/c7aed0f38440f5572b5c84a67d217e9e.png

Comment: what unity version are you using? i tested it with 5.1.2 and don't have that checkmark box from your screenshot.

Comment: I'm using unity 5.0 (can't upgrade to 5.1 because of integrated analytics)

Comment: Anyway, looks like unity guys makes this feature to work properly. Thanks for answer.